# Original Samba server (to acces Lubuntu from Mac) was working. After installing Apache2 on Lubuntu connection fails

Tags: lubuntu, apache2, samba

On a Lubuntu 20.04 system I had a Samba server with two shares (anonymous and secured) working fine. I saw and could select either from my MacOS (BigSur 11.4) and transfer files between the two systems - both on my local LAN.

Then I installed Apache2 server on my Lubuntu 20.04 and I can indeed load the Apache2 Ubuntu default page. BUT I can no longer connect to my samba server on the same Lubuntu system from my Mac. I checked that the ports.conf file has 'Listen 80' in it, so Apache2 only listens to port 80 and not port 445 which SMB uses. smbstatus gives me an answer (Version 4.11.6-Ubuntu), however with little further info, but is shows the samba deamon is running.

I have no idea how to solve this issue? Samba directory and Apache2 directories are different (/etc/samba/.. and /etc/apache2/.. /var/www/...

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you sure that Samba is using 443? Generally the Samba TCP port is 445 

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mistyped. It is 445. (I corrected it above) In the mean time I see the packets arriving at my interface for port 445 (using wireshark): First there comes a netbios (mac addresses match sender/receiver) followed by an IP.  These are retransmitted after approx. 1 second (I think )  But there NEVER is an answer from my SMB server.

Comment: Packets are not answered, whether Apache server runs or is stopped.  I must conclude from this that the installation of Apache2 broke the forwarding of packets to port 445. (and probably many other ports too?)  Despite the ports.conf file having "Listen 80" in it?

Comment: anyone out there who knows how to fix this, or what I might have done wrong?

Comment: Don't know the problem: I see the smb packets arriving at my Lubuntu machine (wireshark) but they do not arrive at the SMBD ( log level = 1), neither do I see them arriving at my Apache2 httpd.  Somewhere Ubuntu discards these packets and I decided to discard samba.  This is too much .....

Answer (score 0):

OMG  - installing Apache2 also enables the ufw in Ubuntu (20.04) - and of course all incoming connections are denied, except the ones needed for Apache2.  Adding 'samba' to the ufw solves this.  This is really wicked! (and cost me two days.)